# How to load external JS file in MVC Model (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller, view

**Hi, i want load spesific js file in my view **

How i can load **dashboard.js** in **DashboardView.php**

Here's my code

**dashboard.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    App.init();
    Dashboard.init();
});
```

**DashboardView.js**

```
<html>  
<head>
    <!-- <script src='<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/script/dashboard.js'></script> --> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    *my content*        
</div>
<!-- end row -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot . Any help is very much appreciated!